# Flutter web build - blank page and stops on web_entrypoint.dart file

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to build a Flutter web fr my app project.

After passing "Flutter Create ." and trying to run in Chrome it shows a blank page and stops on the web_entrypoint.dart file.

Anyone knows what could be wrong?[image]

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you want to remove the `Future<void>` before `main`

```dart
Future<void> main() async{} //<--- remove Future<void>

// do
void main() async{
  /* body */
}
```

Comment: Hi, this is not my code but a Flutter generated file. Seems the problem is somewhere else